# Use sessionstorage to store the values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, session-storage

Please help.  I need my array to save when I goto another page.  Since the page refreshes it loses the array.  From here my code stops at the beginning of the store it function when I try to use sessionstorage.

Here is my attempt.  The array part is just to remove the duplicate from and array and place it into array b.
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Session Storage Attempt</title>
    <script src="untitled-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="doIt()">Button</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onClick="storeIt()">Store It</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let a = [];
let b = [];

function doIt(){
    a.push("a");
    let len = a.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1){
            b.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    alert(b);
}


function storeIt(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('bee', JSON.stringify(b));
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('bee'));

    alert(bee);
}
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123241/5326451

Comment: I tried those and for some odd reason it stops working.

Comment: Then I'd recommend starting from a simpler example and build from that. There's a lot of unknowns in your code snippet so it's hard to follow and debug.

Comment: I just updated it.